# how to correctly pass data structures between custom llvm passes

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault, llvm

I have a `Function` pass, called `firstPass`, which does some analysis and populates:

```
A a;
```

where

```
typedef std::map< std::string, B* > A;
class firstPass : public FunctionPass {  
   A a;
}

typedef std::vector< C* > D;
class B {
   D d;
}

class C {
   // some class packing information about basic blocks;
}
```

Hence I have a map of vectors traversed by `std::string`.
I wrote associated destructors for these classes. This pass works successfully on its own.

I have another `Function` pass, called `secondPass`, needing this structure of type `A` to make some transformations. I used

```
bool secondPass::doInitialization(Module &M) {
  errs() << "now running secondPass\n";
  a = getAnalysis<firstPass>().getA();
  return false;
}

void secondPass::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
  AU.addRequired<firstPass>();
  AU.setPreservesAll();
}
```

The whole code compiles fine, but I get a segmentation fault when printing this structure at the end of my first pass *only if I call my second pass (since `B*` is null)*.

To be clear:

```
opt -load ./libCustomLLVMPasses.so -passA < someCode.bc
```

prints in `doFinalization()` and exits successfully

```
opt -load ./libCustomLLVMPasses.so -passA -passB < someCode.bc
```

gives a segmentation fault.

How should I wrap this data structure and pass it to the second pass without issues? I tried `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw ones but I couldn't make it work. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach anyway, so any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
I solved the problem of seg. fault. It was basically me calling getAnalysis in doInitialization(). I wrote a ModulePass to combine my firstPass and secondPass whose runOnModule is shown below.

```
bool MPass::runOnModule(Module &M) {
  for(Function& F : M) {
    errs() << "F: " << F.getName() << "\n";
    if(!F.getName().equals("main") && !F.isDeclaration())
      getAnalysis<firstPass>(F);
  }

  StringRef main = StringRef("main");
  A& a = getAnalysis<firstPass>(*(M.getFunction(main))).getA();

  return false;
 }
```

This also gave me to control the order of the functions processed.
Now I can get the output of a pass but cannot use it as an input to another pass. I think this shows that the passes in llvm are self-contained.

Comment: did you manage to connect the 2 passes without a 3rd one higher level (`Module`) pass?

Comment: No unfortunately. I experimented with a PassMananger. For this I checked, LPPassManager. This allows me to get passes to be run in a vector and invoke them on loops. My firstPass must run on functions only and secondPass should again run on functions but transform the loops that are accumulated to this data structure that I'm try in to pass secondPass. This is doable but I want my firstPass to be completed on all functions before secondPass starts. Llvm passes run consecutively on structures(function in my case). So firstPass runs on function F, then secondPass runs on function F, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not going to comment on the quality of the data structures based on their C++ merit (it's hard to comment on that just by this minimal example).

Moreover, I wouldn't use the `doInitialization` method, if the actual initialization is that simple, but this is a side comment too. (The [doc](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) does not mention anything explicitly about it, but if it is ran once per `Module` while the `runOn` method is ran on every `Function` of that module, it might be an issue).

I suspect that the main issue seems to stem from the fact `A a` in your `firstPass` is bound to the lifetime of the pass object, which is over once the pass is done. The simplest change would be to allocate that object on the heap (e.g. `new`) and return a pointer to it when calling `getAnalysis<firstPass>().getA();`.

Please note that using this approach might require manual cleanup if you decide to use a raw pointer.

Comment: the structures are fine, accessed several times in the code. Although not shown here I wrote proper destructors in which I delete the objects pointed at and clear the containers. I was suspicious of the lifetime of the objects too and I commented out the relevant portions of the destructors to experiment on this (at the cost of memory leak). It still seg. faulted. the real problem is that I call the analysis in doInitialization(). I'll make an update soon.

Comment: @drunkteapot this was only a suspicion of mine. I've never used the `doInitialization` method and it's not that well documented, IMHO. Moreover, uses of this in LLVM itself are very limited. Lastly, all passes in LLVM that I've seen transfer data around using pointers.

Comment: I agree. doInitialization and doFinalization are rarely called in llvm's source too. They need to be handled with care. (Assuming that there was no other problem) I saw that doFinalization is called after all run* methods which means if I get the analysis of secondPass in runModule shown above, doFinalization() of firstPass will run even after run* methods of secondPass are completed. I'm confused about the ordering of all these Pass related methods